# Adding a class attribute on a Swatch element to disable it isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

I've been trying to disable a swatch element whose data-swatch-option value is Box or "Box and Card" by adding the class `class="swatch--disabled"`. I do only want to use pure JavaScript without any library to do this. Below is the code I wrote to set the attribute. It is noticed that class name with double - in it like `swatch--disabled` is not being considered.

```
JavaScript:
      // Get the element that displays Box swatch and "Box and Card" swatch
      // Deactivate Box and "Box and Card" swatch
      // Add appropriate copy for the alert
  let productSwatches = document.querySelectorAll(".swatches__holder span");
  productSwatches.forEach(element => {
    let attributeValue = element.getAttribute("data-swatch-option");
    console.log("data-swatch-option=" + attributeValue);
    if (attributeValue == "Box") {
      element.setAttribute("class", "swatch--disabled");
    }
    if (attributeValue == "Box and Card") {
      element.setAttribute("class", "swatch--disabled");
    }
  });
HTML:

<div class="swatches__holder">
        <h4 class="h-reset swatches__title">Add My Design To: <span data-swatch-selected-name="6947439312956-1"></span></h4>
                        <span data-swatch-option="Box" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-1" data-booster-initd="true" disabled="true">Box</span>
                    
                        <span data-swatch-option="Card" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-1" data-booster-initd="true">Card</span>
                        <span data-swatch-option="Box and Card" data-swatch-index="6947439312956-1" data-booster-initd="true" disabled="true">Box and Card</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in css
make swatch--disabled important

in js
use classList.add or classList.remove or classList.add

mdn
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList